# AuthnRequest without Signature using SAML on Gitlab

Tags: ruby, gitlab, saml

I try to implement SSO on Gitlab using SAML 2.0 and i have some problems.

The managers of the IdP in my company sent me their metadatas and following the Gitlab documentation about SAML I configured Gitlab like this.

```ruby
gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['saml']
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_ldap_user'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_saml_user'] = false

gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] =
[
   {
name: "saml",
args:
{
assertion_consumer_service_url: "https://my.domain.com/gitlab/auth/saml/callback",
idp_cert: "
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
IDP_Certificate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
",
idp_sso_target_url: "https://my_idp_target_URL",
issuer: "sp-gitlab",
name_identifier_format: "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified",

},
label: "SSO"
}
 ]
```

I sent my metadatas to the the IdP and they were accepted.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" validUntil="2017-11-22T09:24:33Z" ID="_1910909d-5325-4cba-a56f-4f9082e05e24" entityID="sp-gitlab">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>
            My cert
</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>
            Mycert
    </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://my.domain.com/gitlab/auth/saml/callback" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
        <md:AttributeConsumingService index="1" isDefault="true">
            <md:ServiceName xml:lang="en">Required attributes</md:ServiceName>
            <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Email address" Name="email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"/>
            <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Full name" Name="name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"/>
            <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Given name" Name="first_name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"/>
            <md:RequestedAttribute FriendlyName="Family name" Name="last_name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"/>
        </md:AttributeConsumingService>
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

When I try to connect to Gitlab using SSO I  have an error. The signature of my AuthnRequest is absent. IdP’s managers told me the problem comes from the certificate of my application.
So here is my conf about Gitlab HTTPS

```ruby
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 443
...
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/prod.cer"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/prod.key"
```

My instance of Gitlab is running behind an Apache Proxy and the certificate used for Gitlab is also used for the website on this Apache.

So why I don't have a Signature in my AuthnRequest ? Where am I wrong or what did I miss ?

P.S. : I am very new to SAML and Gitlab Configuration so I probably missed something obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your certificate and private key into the gitlab parameters. Also, you need to specify the security parameters to enable the generation of the signature.

This is an sample :

```
gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_sign_in_with_provider'] = 'saml'
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_saml_user'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
    {
        name: 'saml',
        args: {
            assertion_consumer_service_url: 'https://mywebsite/users/auth/saml/callback',
            assertion_consumer_service_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
            idp_cert_fingerprint: '77:EE:EE:AA:67:FA:78:4C:E2:ED:E8:57:AC:EE:AC:AB:AA:FF:FD:FD',
            idp_sso_target_url: 'https://idp.url/auth/SSOPOST/metaAlias/ent/providerIDP',
            idp_sso_target_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
            idp_slo_target_url: 'https://idp.url/auth/IDPSloPOST/metaAlias/ent/providerIDP',
            idp_slo_target_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
            sso_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
            protocol_binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
            issuer: 'sp_gitlab',
            name_identifier_format: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',
            certificate: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDzjCCArYCCQCxUOzAVm5w3DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBqDELMAkGA1UEBhMC
....
v84ULsyAgv8sVJ4XerZ9wr7B
-----END CERTIFICATE-----",
            private_key: "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAxcTsJ0sBMAH9NwEvDT5qcGBA6JiChtM90I9di7YC98lO5qFM
....
lfIj9QAaFdL9lPskg6zX6HEooOEoLib8fm9IZCIChjhsdjoj/6QXP6k=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
            security: {
                authn_requests_signed: true,
                embed_sign: true,
                digest_method: "XMLSecurity::Document::SHA1",
                signature_method: "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"
            }
        },
        label: 'SAML Auth'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no signatures in AuthnRequest according to my knowledge and experience. Signing or encryption starts in next HTTP requests.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#Authentication_Request_Protocol

What and where are you getting errors if any?

(Example) Authnrequest doesn't have signatures:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                    ID="_a976498d2ebe858cc56d486b5af2085ed957f45c5a"
                    Version="2.0"
                    IssueInstant="2017-08-10T13:29:09Z"
                    Destination="https://<idp_url>/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO"
                    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://<mahara_adress>/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp"
                    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                    >
    <saml:Issuer>https://<mahara_adress>/mahara</saml:Issuer>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```